# BitbucketBackup - Overcome Git fetch non-fast-forward error

Tags: git

I am using [BitBucket Backup](http://christianspecht.de/bitbucket-backup/) to backup my team's repository locally.

It works fine. Except that recently I was cleaning up old repositories (that came from CVS and SVN) and while doing that I had rebased the repositories in bitbucket.

As a result Bitbucket Backup is not updating my local copy.

It uses the command `git fetch <repo url> refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*`.

It fails with error

> [rejected] master   --> master (non-fast-forward)

That makes total sense, and it would be fine for a human user, but somehow I need to tell the git fetch that if it gets a non-fast-forward error to kill the local repository and just download everything from scratch.

Is there such an option for git fetch?

Otherwise I would need to detect the issue in Bitbucket Backup and clean up the folder myself (but that would be more involved).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's such an option: `--force` (or just `-f`). Quoting [**the doc**](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch):

> When `git fetch` is used with `<rbranch>:<lbranch>` refspec, it refuses to
>   update the local branch `<lbranch>` unless the remote branch `<rbranch>`
>   it fetches is a descendant of `<lbranch>`. This option overrides that
>   check.

Comment: I tried that before, it finished successfully, but I believe that what it does is that it forces the tip to match. I just tested it again: the things I had deleted remain in the repository - so I would end up with a backup that is not an exact clone of bitbucket (not good).

Comment: Sorry, not sure I follow you here: what are those `things` still in the repo despite you have deleted them? It's not files, I suppose, as `fetch` by itself doesn't update the working copy; you'll have to checkout it afterwards.

Comment: Things = branches. Before rebasing my code I had some braches that I deleted. Those branches are in the backup repository (that was failing because of the non-fast-forward). After using the --force option, and uploading the resulting repository to bitbucket (a new repository to test)... I get the old/deleted branches there. BTW: this is a bare repository (no working copy).

Comment: So, what I assume that git fetch --force does is that is downloads the commits that I don't have, and force the HEAD to match... but it doesn't delete the extra commits that I have locally.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't this issue be dealt with `--prune` option?

Comment: I think that's it - I am honestly not 100% sure because I lost my testing environment. I am implementing that plus a period delete of the whole backup folder. That will accomplish what I need.